# Is there a way to put Google Analytics for web into "dry run" mode like the GA mobile SDKs?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, analytics.js

In Google Analytics mobile SDKs for both Android and iOS there is a flag you can set to put them into what's called "dry run" mode. Without changing any of your code, events won't be sent to Google when this is flipped on. Here's the documentation for the feature on [Android](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/advanced#testing) and [iOS](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/advanced#testing).

This is really helpful for avoiding event tracking locally or in development and testing environments.

My question is whether there is any API in Google Analytics for web that works identically? I can't seem to find anything in the docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try and disable the `sendHitTask` or instead just log the hits to console? [developers.google.com](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/tasks#disabling) explains how to disable the `sendHitTask`.

```
ga('set', 'sendHitTask', function (model) {
  console.log(model.get('hitPayload'));
});
```

You can also try and send the hits to [validation server](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/validating-hits) to get some basic validation result.

Comment: This does seem like the best option at this point. Strange that they don't just create a 'dry-run' flag on the ga object or a tracker object which just does this.

Comment: I am one of the devs who wrote the script :). I'll take your suggestion back to the team and see what can be done. So far, we have not seen any requests for dry_run flag and hence not added it.